# Why Proxy Server Not Working On Some Apps

Tags: windows-7, firewall, port, proxy-server

I hosted proxy server on my windows 7 PC so I can share the internet to my other mobile devices, the proxy server port is set to 6588.

I've set HTTP/HTTPS to port 6588, and my firewall rules is set to open to all port and another rules specifically open for 6588.

If I have an application that is trying to outbound at port 4070 will it get through my proxy server.

Because spotify on my smartphone won't work when the connected to internet by proxy, other apps like Facebook, Instagram, Youtube and web browser have no issue with connecting to internet.

Answer (score 0):

Because that app does not support network connection with Proxy or you set bypass proxy on that app. You can open port 4070 on your firewall.